# android json and decoding arabic characters

Tags: php, android, json

i have an android application and i have this php page that's responsible for selecting data from db the problem is that the arabic data are displayed as "\u062d\u0630\u0627\u0621 \u0643\u0631\u0629 \u0642\u062f\u0645" ... i tried all the solutions provided here but nothing worked so here's my php code.
N.B: my host uses PHP 5.4

```
    <?php

$link = mysql_connect("******","******","******");
$db= mysql_select_db("******") or die("Cannot select Database.");

$response = array();
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci"); 

$sql1 = "select p.Name, p.Brand, p.ImageUrl , p.Price, t.Type
        from Product p inner join Type t on p.Type_ID = t.ID
        order by StockDate desc
        ";


$result1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());


if (mysql_num_rows($result1) > 0){
// looping through all results
// products node
$response["product"] = array();

while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))) {
    // temp user array
    $product = array();
    $product["Name"] = $row["Name"];
    $product["Type"] = $row["Type"];
    $product["Price"] = $row["Price"];
    $product["Brand"] = $row["Brand"];
    $product["ImageUrl"] = $row["ImageUrl"];
    $product["StockDate"] = $row["StockDate"];

    // push single job into final response array
    array_push($response["product"], $product);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
die(json_encode($response));
           } else {
// no products found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No Products found";

// echo no users JSON
die(json_encode($response));
```

}
        ?>

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is with Json; you are storing the Arabic characters into sql db incorrectly.

Try adding this in the head of the page you use to insert into the sql db (the page that contains the form):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

and add this attribute to the form:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

and before inserting and selecting the form table, use this:

```
mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");
```